# RenderScript: do not provide .so in aar

Tags: android, renderscript, aar

I'm currently building a SDK and I provide a .aar archive to the users of the SDK.

I got an optional feature in my SDK that basically blurs the image.
However, this feature requires to use renderScript which make the .aar archive larger due to the presence of shared libraries.

```
./jni/armeabi-v7a:
total 3752
rw-rr- 1 cylix wheel 1,1M 29 nov 16:16 libblasV8.so
rw-rr- 1 cylix wheel 746K 29 nov 16:16 libRSSupport.so
rw-rr- 1 cylix wheel 46K 29 nov 16:16 librsjni.so
./jni/mips:
total 5224
rw-rr- 1 cylix wheel 1,5M 29 nov 16:16 libblasV8.so
rw-rr- 1 cylix wheel 1,0M 29 nov 16:16 libRSSupport.so
rw-rr- 1 cylix wheel 70K 29 nov 16:16 librsjni.so
./jni/x86:
total 5344
rw-rr- 1 cylix wheel 1,6M 29 nov 16:16 libblasV8.so
rw-rr- 1 cylix wheel 958K 29 nov 16:16 libRSSupport.so
rw-rr- 1 cylix wheel 54K 29 nov 16:16 librsjni.so
./jni/arm64-v8a:
total 1808
rw-rr- 1 cylix wheel 843K 29 nov 16:16 libRSSupport.so
rw-rr- 1 cylix wheel 60K 29 nov 16:16 librsjni.so
```

But I have noticed that if I remove the libraries and don't provide them in the .aar, the client of the library can still enable renderScript on its side and access the feature without any problem.

Then, I just have to check in my code if renderScript is available:

```
    try {
        Class.forName("android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        //! renderScript not available
    }
```

But here is my issue.
I still need to put in my gradle file:

```
renderscriptTargetApi 23
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

otherwise, the project can't compile.
But this causes the automatic inclusion of the .so files listed above...

Is there any way to counter that: being able to compile the renderScript features but filter the .so files so that they are not included in the .aar archive?

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are better solutions. But the low hanging fruit here is to use com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0 or higher.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
    // ...
}
```

gradle plugin 2.2.0+ will not bundle libblasV8.so unless you specify `renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled true`. This way your AAR file will probably reduce 50% weight.

Answer (score 1):

Miao's answer worked for me, but I had a few more ideas.

If all you need is blur, you might be able to avoid support.v8 all together, and just use native RenderScript sdk.

It depends on your minSdkVerison and needs. [ScriptIntrinsicBlur](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBlur.html) was added in 17, or you could also just use a custom .rs kernel. It would be less performant than the ScriptIntrinsic, but it would let you support older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out a solution. Maybe not the clean one, but at least it works.

I simply copied the renderscript-v8.jar from the android SDK library of my computer and put it into my project as a dependency.

Then, I removed the Gradle file configuration of renderscript

```
renderscriptTargetApi 23
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

That way, I can compile thanks to the .jar and I dont have any heavy .so in my .aar because Gradle doesn't build any of them anymore automatically.

Then, the user of my SDK can either chose to enable renderscript or not.

Comment: It works because you are testing on devices that don't need the support library fallbacks. This is not a good answer though, because when you run on older devices, the code will crash when looking for those shared objects.